# What does this offset represent?

Tags: c#, stack-trace, managed

I have a managed stack trace from an AppVerifier session.

```
STACK_TEXT:   0019c014 1f75b1f0 
carson!KapprisPrintCacheNS.SpecCache.MatchJobInt+0xd8 0019c130 1f75a067 
carson!KapprisPrintCacheNS.SpecCache.JobEvent+0x3e7 0019c2b0 1f759bf4 
kofficecontrol!DomainBoundILStubClass.IL_STUB_COMtoCLR+0x3c 0019e36c 53177331 mscorlib_ni!System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember+0x341 0019e4c4 537f61eb 
mscorlib_ni!System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember+0x15f 0019e8a4 1f75097a kofficecontrol!KOfficeControl.ProgressIndicator.onFormProgress+0x1a 0019e8c0 1f75094c 
. . .
```

This tells me that the faulting call was at `MatchJobInt+0xd8` but I don't know what the `0xd8` represents. Is it a byte offset? Or a managed instruction offset? Or something else?

I'd like somehow to map the `0xd8` back onto the original C# source code to see what AppVerifier is complaining about.

Comment: Add options to compiler : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ds95cz0(v=vs.71).aspx.  and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287473(v=vs.71).aspx (see debugging).

Comment: Here is the page for 2013 (last posting was 2003). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/listed-alphabetically

Comment: Specifically *which* compiler options should I add?

Comment: Not sure.  Been a long time since I've used these options.  There should be an option called "create map", but microsoft never makes it that easy.  There is also an option to to create a C# list file with the assembly offset on the list.

Answer (score 0):

It represents the number of bytes (in terms of instructions/opcodes) from the start of the function

In your example above it's 0xd8 bytes (216 bytes in decimal) from the entry point of `MatchJobInt`